# How to make the prediction from cross validation score?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, cross-validation, sklearn-pandas

I am working on building a prediction model. I have managed to reach until getting the cross-validation scores. Now I have no idea how to continue. What function should I use to make predictions using cross-validation scores?

```py
X = data.iloc[:,0:16]
Y = data.iloc[:,16]
validation_size = 0.20
seed = 7
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y,
test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)
models = [
    ('LR', LogisticRegression()),
    ('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()),
    ('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()),
    ('SVM', SVC())
]

results, names = [], []
for name, model in models:
    seed = 32
    scoring = 'accuracy'
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

Comment: Cross validation scores are used to select the model that performs best  for the given application and data, they are not for making predictions. You can then take the model with the best CV score and use that model for making predictions.

Answer (score 0):

Cross validation is mostly used as a more robust validation scheme to check if your model is performing well or not. After that you can train a model with the whole dataset after being satisfied with your cross validation score or you can use.

```
sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict
```

Which predicts cross validated estimates. You can check out the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html) for more information.

Comment: ```
cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
```
I understand that the above set of code give the accuracy estimates of the model built from train data.

```
Y_pred = model_selection.cross_val_predict(classifier,X_validation,Y_validation, cv=kfold)
```
Does the above prediction function use the existing model we built from the train data? I cannot see how the model we built is passed to this function. Also, why do we have to pass the output to the prediction function?

Comment: You can pass any model you want to the function. As for the y, according to the documentation you can skip it.